Alphabetically sort mongodb result
const searchUser = asyncHandler(
    async (req: AuthenticatedRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
        const { name = "" } = req.query;

        const users = await User.aggregate(
            [
                {
                    $match: {
                        _id: { $ne: new Types.ObjectId(req.userId) },
                    },
                },
                {
                    $match: {
                        name: { $regex: name, $options: "i" },
                    },
                },
                {
                    $sort: { name: 1 },
                },
                {
                    $project: {
                        _id: 1,
                        name: 1,
                        avatar: 1,
                    },
                },
            ],
            { collation: { locale: "en", strength: 1, caseLevel: true, caseFirst: "lower" } }
        );

        return res.status(200).json({ success: true, status: 200, users });
    }
);

I am building search user end point and in that i want all the users except the current user and i want results in sorted order according to user's name. I want that lowercase come first, then uppercase.
For example:
"john Doe",
"John Doe"
"Maxtern"
How can i do this using collation?

Create an auxiliary field with $toLower to convert the name into lower case first, named lowerCased. Then, $sort by {lowerCased: 1, name: -1} to sort the name insensitive to case. If there is a tie scenario by different case, the raw name field will be the tie breaker.
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      lowerCased: {
        "$toLower": "$name"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      lowerCased: 1,
      name: -1
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground

But i want to use collation, can you tell me how to do this with the help of collation

@BhomikRanjan any problem with a plain {locale: "en", caseFirst: "lower"}?

Yes, bro
"BhoMik",
"bhomik Ranjan",
"Bhomik Ranjan"
I have these 3 names in my db, and when i am using {locale: "en", caseFirst: "lower"} these are coming in this order, but i want "bhomik Ranjan" should come first

@BhomikRanjan Can you please edit your question to show what you are seeing exactly? It is not replicable on my side, nor on the mongoplayground. Your expected sorting is working fine with locale.

caseFirst: "lower" is not working.
I have "BhoMik", "bhomik Ranjan", "Bhomik Ranjan" these names in my database.
When i am using lower sorted order is "BhoMik", "bhomik Ranjan", "Bhomik Ranjan", but it should be "bhomik Ranjan", "BhoMik", "Bhomik Ranjan"

@BhomikRanjan That's because "BhoMik" and "bhomik Ranjan" are not equal even when case-insensitive. "BhoMik" is a shorter word, so it will get sorted first. And what you're asking now is quite different from what you asked in your question, which ray already answered. Read "What should I do when someone answers my question?", and about Voting and Accepting.

@BhomikRanjan What you need to do is split first & last names but even then, the last name missing means it's either first or last in your results (with null or compare.MAX). So "BhoMik" will not be in the middle as you want. You'll need to have more sort fields like firstNameLower firstName lastNameLower lastName but that breaks case-insensitive sorting after the firstName.

@aneroid Thanks for the help and your explanation. I think my answer is not actually addressing OP's concern on locale usage anyway so I will probably delete this answer after OP see your message. Feel free to post as a standalone answer and I will help to vote it up.

@ray Your answer addresses the "john Doe", "John Doe", "Maxtern" ordering OP wanted. Now doing "john smith" vs "JoHn" vs just "john" is a bit of a modification. I'll post an answer later if I have time but will wait for OP to confirm what the result should be. Where should "BHOMIK" appear in a list like "BhoMik", "bhomik Ranjan", "Bhomik Ranjan", "BHOMIK"?
